# Code::Blocks Issue; "It seems that this project has not been built yet. Do you want to build it now?"

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, codeblocks

I write my code, it builds fine (no errors or warnings), then I hit "run" and it asks what I got in the title. I hit yes, then it asks it again. I hit yet, and nothing happens.

The strange thing is, my code works perfectly fine in Visual Studio. The code is meant to print a 3x3 grid to the console, like this:

```
123
456
789
```

The code is very simple:

```
int main()
{
    int arrayTest[3][3] =
{
    {1,2,3},
    {4,5,6},
    {7,8,9}
};
for (int j = 0; j < 3 ; j++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++)
    {
        cout << arrayTest[j][i];
    }

  cout << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

The issue I find (In this case), is line 13 (Though no errors show). I can change line 13 a little bit and it works, but no changes are needed in Visual Studio.

```
 //Option one:
cout << arrayTest[j][i] << "";
```

Notice it works fine as soon as I simply add << ""; on the end of the line. Then it runs as expected.

```
//Option two:
cout << arrayTest[j][i];
cout.flush();
```

Adding cout.flush(); stops the issue from happening also.

Also removing

```
cout << endl;
```

From line 16 works too. So does anyone know why I am getting such specific issues?

Additional info:

OS: Windows 8.1
IDE: Code::Blocks
Compiler: MinGW (The one that comes with Code:Blocks)

Build log:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in Hello World (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -std=c++11 -c "C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Programming\C++\Code Blocks\Hello World\main.cpp" -o obj\Debug\main.o mingw32-g++.exe -o "bin\Debug\Hello World.exe" obj\Debug\main.o
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 3 second(s)) 0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))
```

Comment: Is the issue about a console window disappearing?

Comment: "it asks what I got in the title"  Please clarify what you mean by this.

Comment: I mean it asks what I said in the title of the question

Comment: No, the console window doesn't appear. It is not an issue with the it flashing up and then going, as code blocks doesn't let this happen (Tells you stuff on console window when "0" is returned in main.)

Comment: I have found that unticking "debug" when making a new project fixes my issue, but does that cause problems later down the line when I want to debug?